# How to export URLs in org-mode to ascii without brackets

Tags: git, url, export, ascii, org-mode

When I write

```
$ git clone https://https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
```

in org-mode and then export to ascii (C-c C-e a) the result is

```
$ git clone [https://https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git]
```

Hence, the reader of the ReadMe wouldn't be able to simply copy&paste that line.

I'd like to write my ReadMe files for GIT projects in org-mode (emacs) and export them to ascii.
This would be very nice, because the formatting is beautiful and the content of the ReadMe.txt file is automatically displayed on github and bitbucket.

What is the preferred way to get rid of the brackets? Define the line in org-mode as a code snippet? Change the ascii export definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest marking those commands as literal examples, either enclosing between `#+begin_example` and `#+end_example`, or prefixing with a colon for single lines:

```
This is an example command:
: $ git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git
```

The links won't be interpreted.